# nivo slider caption outside the picture

Tags: jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I want to show different texts on left side of the pictures with nivo slider and make it slide like pictures. I tried different solutions and I coudn't move text outside of picture, because when I add negative value to the left, my caption dissapears - it is wissible just on the picture. So question is how to set position of caption outside the image - that is not part of the image? How can I achieved this? Maybe nivo slider is not the right way for this?

```
                          -----------------------------------------
                          |                                       |
                          |              image                    |
 -------------            |                                       |
 |  caption   |           |                                       |
 --------------           -----------------------------------------
```

Thanks for the answer.
I have so far this:
HTML

```
    <div id="feature-text-01" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <p><h2>Title 1</h2></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feature-text-02" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <p><h2>Title 2</h2></p>
        <p>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feature-text-03" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <p><h2>Title 3</h2></p>
        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="feature-text-04" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <p><h2>Title 4</h2></p>
        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .nivo-caption { 
        width: 200px; 
        height: 250px; 
        left: -200px; /* same as the width */
    }
```

Comment: can you provide me link where you use it

Comment: Hi, here you can find the page [link](http://213.165.92.107/nivoTest.html). I want caption on left position where is other text now. Final goal si achieve slide text and pic together and have bullets navigation at the bottom. If you know any other solution for this I will appreciate a hint. Thx!

Comment: your caption is cut down do you want o fix that

Comment: caption that comes over imges

Comment: yes I want to fix that like I draw above. I want caption to be on the position where is now the text on the left not over the picture but outside the picture.

Answer (score 2):

### Here is my solution:

Add to your slider call one extra param

```
$('#Myslide').nivoSlider({
    manualCaption: true // Manual caption placement
});
```

Put HTML code to your page, where you want to display slide caption

```
<div id="manual-nivo-caption" class="nivo-caption"></div>
```

Add any CSS to the caption

```
#manual-nivo-caption{
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

After this, we have to put some changes for **jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js**

1st step: Add to the slider dafault params our new param

```
e.fn.nivoSlider.defaults={ ... , manualCaption:false, ... }
```

2nd step: Before the caption added, check our param

replace

```
s.append(e('<div class="nivo-caption"></div>'));
```

with

```
if(!r.manualCaption){s.append(e('<div class="nivo-caption"></div>'));}
```

3rd step: Change caption search from parent-related to global (you will lose posibility to use more than one slider on page, but some easy code modification will deside this problem. It's wasn't important for me.)

replace

```
var n=e(".nivo-caption",s);
```

with

```
var n=e(".nivo-caption");
```

That's all folks.
I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a positive z-index to the caption, then the caption won't disappear behind the other elements but will be on top of everything.

I tried this to the controlnav and it worked perfect, it should also work for the caption.

Comment: Unfortunately it not work for caption. I add z-index and is still the same (z-index: 80;). Caption is cutted off on the left. It could be seen just on the image.

Comment: Here you can see my result [link](http://213.165.92.107/nivoTest.html). I want caption to be on the position of current text on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
please find this css

.futurico-theme .nivo-caption
{
}

and remove 

margin-left:-50px
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define title attribute for  and these styles

```
.nivo-caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 700px;
      top: 150px; /* y offset position */
      overflow: hidden;
      background: none;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 44px;
      text-align: left;
      text-transform: uppercase; /* converts text to UPPERCASE */
      z-index: 8;
  }

  .nivo-caption a {
      display: inline !important;
  }
```

Refrence:
[NIVO SLIDER: HOW TO CHANGE THE CAPTION POSITION FOR EACH SLIDE](http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/Nivo-Slider-change-caption-position-for-each-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

```
      overflow: hidden;
```

from .nivoSlider {} in your CSS it should work.